# How to increment values in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some `checkboxes`. I am retrieving data from the database to populate in the checkbox to determine which one to be checked, in case of others I need to write the values in the `textbox`.

Example: `categories="Coconuts,Apple,Orange"`.

So I need the checkbox `Coconuts` & Others to be checked, and "`Apple`, `Orange`" to be in the `textbox`.

The result I got in the `textbox` is "Apple" only, can anyone help me in that?

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"EditFarmerData.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data:{'EditFarmerID': EditFarmerID},
  success: function (data) {
    for (x in data.categories) { 
      switch(data.categories[x]) {   
        case'Cacao':
          $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Cacao]").prop("checked",true);
          break;

        case'Coconuts':
          $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Coconuts]").prop("checked",true);
          break;

        case'Bananas':
          $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Bananas]").prop("checked",true);
          break;

        case'':
          $('#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
          $("#Editotherproduct").val("") ;
          break;

        default:
          $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Others]").prop("checked",true);
          $("#Editotherproduct").val(data.categories[x]);
          break;
      } 
    } 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this, simple approach would be to use string concatenation of old value in textbox + new value to appended in textbox

```
$.each(data.categories, function(key, value) {
    switch(data.categories[x])
    {
        case'Cacao':
            $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Cacao]").prop("checked",true);
        break;

        case'Coconuts':
            $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Coconuts]").prop("checked",true);
        break;

        case'Bananas':
            $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Bananas]").prop("checked",true);
        break;

        case'':
            $('#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
            $("#Editotherproduct").val("") ;
        break;

        default:
            $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Others]").prop("checked",true);
            var temp = $("#Editotherproduct").val();
            $("#Editotherproduct").val(temp+","+value);
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `default` case when you set the value to the  `$("#Editotherproduct")`, it will always updates to the last one.

To solve this, you should first get the current value :

```
var currentOtherProductValue = $("#Editotherproduct").val();
```

Then add [concate] with existing values, you can do it as your way,

here is simple solution:

```
    default:
      $("#EditFarmerForm input[type=checkbox][value=Others]").prop("checked",true);
      var currentOtherProductValue = $("#Editotherproduct").val()                        
      $("#Editotherproduct").val(currentOtherProductValue+','+ data.categories[x]);
      break;
```

Comment: Thank you,but i have small problem that there is always "," in the beginning of textbox

Comment: you can check if "currentOtherProductValue" have some value, then add the value, other wise just set the value. for Ex: check with if($.trim(currentOtherProductValue)) then go with comma, otherwise just set value